# WPF datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to figure out how WPF data binding works.
(Warning : I'm new to WPF, and C# in general.)

I'm trying to build a window that would display simple data, in read only mode.
I made 3 test cases in 3 stackPanel shown below:

```
    <Window x:Class="BindingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="360" Width="600">

    <StackPanel>
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="window Title = " />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
        </WrapPanel>
        
        <WrapPanel>
            <Button Name="btn1" Content="test" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </WrapPanel>
        
        <WrapPanel>
            
            <TextBlock Text="user is :" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=husband.FirstName}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName,ElementName=husband}" />
            <TextBlock Text="married to :" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding wife.DisplayName}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
        </WrapPanel>
        
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code Behind This :

```
    namespace BindingTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public User husband;
        public User wife;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            husband = new User() { FirstName = "john", LastName = "Lennon" };
            wife = new User() { FirstName = "yoko", LastName = "Ono" };
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            btn1.Content = this.Title; //works.
            btn1.Content = this.husband;//calls toString() and works
        }
    }

    public class User
    {

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string DisplayName { get { return FirstName +" " +LastName; } }
        
        public override string ToString()
        {
                return LastName +"," +FirstName;
        }

    }
}
```

the First two stackPanel works :
I have a dataContext, from which I can read the MainWindow.Title Property.

pressing the button I can access the Title property, and the husband property

in the 3rd stackPanel, I try to achieve the same with data binding markup, but the debugger tell it cannot find the husband property. I tried many syntax, with no results...

I tried initializing datacontext this way :
this.Datacontext = husband;
which work, but prevent access to other variables such as wife

What Am I missing, and how Can I have a datacontext with more than one variable?

Comment: "the husband property". in your sample it is not a *property*, it is a *field*. Important difference for Binding. `this.DataContext = this;` is a strange thing to do. if you need to bind to some other ui element, use `RelativeSource` in Binding or `ElementName`

Comment: `DataContext = this;` is what you typically do in the constructor of a MainWindow without a view model, but with properties that serve as source properties for bindings. Still better to put the properties in a separate class (e.g. called ViewModel), and set `DataContext = new ViewModel();`.

Comment: Ash is right.  Add {get; set;} to the husband / wife as bindable PROPERTIES of the "this" form.

Comment: @ASH, DRapp : Oh, Thanks ! It works now.

Comment: @Clemens I like the idea of having a seperate class dedicated to datacontext. Since I'm still learning, i'll keep the code as simple as possible for my (not so) trivial case.